# Is it possible to start native file manager in android on any device and platform?

Tags: android, file, browser, android-intent, file-management

For example on Samsung

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

you can start the native file manager with the above snippet , but how can I start native file manager on any platform and any device and any android API level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to start native file manager in android on any device and platform?

Android does not have a "native file manager". Some devices might ship with some sort of file manager app pre-installed, but that is up to the device manufacturer, and not all devices will have one.

Comment: is there any trick that I can start the installed file manager on the phone ? (of course if one is present), what is the right way to do this ?

Comment: @Lukap: "is there any trick that I can start the installed file manager on the phone ? " -- contact each of the hundreds of Android device manufacturers and ask them. There are no documented standards in this area, nor am I aware of some master catalog of file managers.